# Showing the triviality of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Just starting to properly learn the chapter on homomorphisms, and it will be great if I can understand the following question I have:

How could I actually show that when there are two groups $G$ and $H$ (finite), and $|G|$ and $|H|$ are coprime, then then homomorphism $\Phi:G \rightarrow H$ must be trivial.

My idea: Since $Im(\phi)$ and $Ker(\phi)$ are respective subgroups of the groups $G$ and $H$, then by Lagrange's Theorem $|Ker(\phi)|||G|$ and $|Im(\phi)|||H|$. I think if we just show that the |$Im(\phi)$| is $1$, then it implies that the $|Ker(\phi)|$ is equal to the order of $G$. Hence $\phi$ must be trivial. But if this is correct, I cant seem to show $|Im(\phi)|=1$. However, is this the correct way?

Can someone please help me show the homomorphism $\Phi$ is trivial if my idea is completely off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track.

To show the image has order $1$, note that the order of the quotient is the order of $G$ divided by the order of the kernel, hence divides the order of $G$. But the order of the image is the same as the order of the quotient, hence divides both the order of $G$ and the order of $H$.